# VBA to include SQL query headers

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need to add the table headers to include in my VBA code, which is connected to SQL. The code is working (as it's spitting out the SQL results on a new worksheet), however it's not grabbing the headers.

Can someone help?

```
Sub SpectrumADGroupMapping()

    'Start Declarations'
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    'Connection string to SQL server/DB (Windows Auth)
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=TEST;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=TESTPC;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=TESTDBNAME"
    Cn.Open 

    Set and Execute SQL Command
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.ActiveConnection = Cn
    rs.Open "Select top 50* from TestTable order by creationDate desc"

    'Copy Data to Excel
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "TestWorkSheet"
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.  (I've just dragged it out of one of my spreadsheets - just changing the names to protect the innocent.)

```
' Write out the Field names as column headings
Dim c As Long
For c = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
    With Worksheets("TestWorkSheet").Cells(1, c)
        .Value = rs.Fields(c - 1).Name

        'The rest is just how we format the headings - leave it in or take it out
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        'End of formatting of headings

    End With
Next c
```

Place that code before your `Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` line (which you should really code as `Worksheets("TestWorkSheet").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` - it's always a good idea to qualify which worksheet you are referring to when using `Range`, `Cells`, etc).

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the cell formatting after the next loop and format the whole header in one go instead of cell by cell?